# Getting Full Package Name for RemovePackageAsync() call

Tags: c#, uwp, package-managers

I have code that installs an appxbundle file using the AddPackageAsync() call from the PackageManager class. I now want to write code that uninstalls the UWP, and I believe I can do that using the RemovePackageAsync() call. The problem I'm dealing with is that I need to pass in a string that represents the package's full name and idk what that looks like. Could someone give me an example of what package full name looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the package full name through a quick use of Get-AppxPackage Powershell cmdlet:

`Name              : king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga
Publisher         : CN=F80C3B33-B9E8-4F23-AB15-B97C700EFF2F
Architecture      : X86
ResourceId        :
Version           : 1.68.500.0
PackageFullName   : king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga_1.68.500.0_x86__kgqvnymyfvs32
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga_1.68.500.0_x86__kgqvnymyfvs32
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga_kgqvnymyfvs32
PublisherId       : kgqvnymyfvs32
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
Dependencies      : {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.24123.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe}`

The value of PackageFullName would be passed to RemovePackageAsync to remove a given package.

You can programmatically enumerate through installed appx packages with a call to [FindPackagesForUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240968.aspx) which will return similar information that Get-AppxPackage does in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to uninstall my app. For anyone needing to know what to type in the cmdlet, type the following: 'Get-AppxPackage -Name PackageName'